# Show progress and estimated time when copy/move files

Tags: emacs, dired

Emacs 25.1, Dired+

When I copy files from one folder to another Emacs NOT show a progress. So I don't know when the process will be finish (not show estimated time).

Does exist any package for this?
Thanks.

Comment: See:  http://oremacs.com/2016/02/24/dired-rsync/ and https://truongtx.me/tmtxt-dired-async.html

Comment: Is ii work on Windows 7 (64 bit)?

Comment: You will need to research the possibilities of using `rsync` on Windows 7 (64bit).

Comment: I try this, but it not work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43309498/windows-emacs-tda-rsync-the-source-and-destination-cannot-both-be-remote